# Sorting averages by highest to lowest in Python from text files

Tags: python, sorting, average

I am trying to sort averages of scores in a class by pupil, from highest to lowest.

Here is my code so far:

```
with open("class.txt") as f:
    d = {}

    for line in f:
        column = line.split(":")
        names = column[0]
        scores = int(column[1].strip())

        count = 0
        while count < 3:
            d.setdefault(names, []).append(scores)
            count = count + 1
    for names, v in sorted(d.items()):
        average = (sum(v)/len(v))
        print(names,average)
    averages=[]
    averages.append(average)
```

I have worked out the averages however, I'm stuck on how I could sort these averages by highest to lowest, here is what ive tried

```
list = sorted(averages, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
```

However, it gives the error..

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I also noticed that it doesn't work the averages of the last three scores only, it works out the average for all the scores of the student in the text file, however I would like it to work out only the three recent scores of each student

I'm quite new to Python and I am not sure what I am doing wrong, so any pointers of help would be much appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Comment: `column[0][Click Here](null)` ???

Comment: Is it permitted to get other people to write your GCSE exam code?

Comment: @thefourtheye oh right, sorry, fixed it now.. no idea how that got there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your averages code a little mixed up. Create your `averages` list *first*, then append each average you compute to that:

```
averages=[]
for name, v in d.items():
    average = (sum(v)/len(v))
    averages.append((name, average))
```

This produces a list of `(name, average)` tuples that you can then sort:

```
for name, average in sorted(averages, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
    print(name, average)
```

Comment: do you perhaps have know how i could go abouts making it only work out the averages of the last three scores of each student instead of the average of all the scores of that student in the file?

Comment: Take `v[-3:]` to get the last 3 from the list, but remove you `while` loop when reading the file; you are adding 3 copies of each score read.

Comment: @PythonFun: any reason you un-accepted my answer? Anything missing still?

Comment: Ooh, no nothing's missing, didn't realise i unaccepted it, I've accepted it again, Thanks for your help :)